# How do I proceed when one leader shoots down the tasks assigned by another leader?

Tags: communication, new-job, productivity

So I am less than a month into a great new job. The CTO assigned me some tasks and then handed me over to the Sen Dev who shot down those tasks as not being that important, which leaves me with not much to do except do my best to learn my way around the current products we are building and maintaining.

I don't know if this is a communication thing being so brand new, but I would like to get back to feeling productive and providing value where I can until I become familiar with our products codebase.

To be clear, its an actual task on the Trello board.

So, it's really concerning me that I get tasks assigned by one leader and then they get shot down by another.

How do I safeguard my future here and mitigate this dynamic?

Comment: Who is your direct boss?

Comment: @DarkCygnus, I have been doing my 1-on-1 with the CTO.

Comment: and why did he "handed you to the sen dev"?

Comment: Not very important tasks are EXACTLY the types of tasks that should be given to someone new to a job.  It helps them be useful as they learn processes and where everything is, without slowing down team members.

Comment: @DarkCygnus, to deal with some business end relationships with clients.

Comment: Did the senior dev tell you to not do the tasks, or did he just say they weren't that useful?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek, that seems right to me, because I tried to jump in on a bug which seems to me what the Sen Dev finds  value in and I realized I was of no use, still knew very little to provide value.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek, just shrugged it off with a tone of, well we are moving off that technology so writing documentation on it is not very useful,  these are my words. The tone is what I am trying to capture here.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, that one was addressing my contributions in general, pointing things out and such. These are actual tasks. The common thread, of  course being the contradiction and thats a concern for me, but a task I realized today, requires slightly different approach than just offering welcomed suggestions or ideas for improvement.

Comment: What do you mean by "handed me over to the Sen Dev" is the senior dev in charge of you and your tasks or is it the CTO?

Comment: Have you explicitly told either leader about the conflict? Or asked *them* how to proceed? I should add, it's still unclear to me from your comment 4 above this one if the Sen Dev literally meant for you to not do the tasks, or if he was just making comments on how he didn't think they were useful (but didn't actually mean to communicate that you should not do them.)

Comment: @dwizum, it was the latter. So when a leader says I don't think they are useful, after another leader told you they would be, where does that leave me? In other words, that affects morale when leadership can't agree and certainly has affected mine. Perhaps I should express, but not good at doing so.

Comment: The key is to do as you're told. If they want to disagree or make side comments, let them. You are responsible for doing what your direct manager tells you to do. **You're not responsible for what other people think of his decisions.** You have a personal choice to make about whether you find those opinions demoralizing or not. I can tell you right now, if you want to have a long and happy career, then sooner or later you're going to have to give up trying to make *everyone* happy, or worrying about what *everyone* thinks.

Comment: @dwizum, working on it.

Comment: @Daniel Based off your previous question I'm just wondering. Did the CTO ask you to fix these problems or only identify them? It sounds like you have just stopped looking and are focusing on the identified issue. Maybe go to your CTO and ask if you are only meant to be identifying possible issues and/or also resolving them? (or if you only resolve them if the other people have time to assist and verify your code)

Comment: @Shadowzee, the pointing stuff out was just a way of saying start contributing, but there were a couple of clear tasks that also got shot down. Its like the two are not on the same page and that puts me in an awkward position, I probably could have solved this, by just asking, "so you don't think I should complete these tasks I was assigned?" Clearly the answer would have been "please complete those tasks". Perhaps he was just thinking out loud, but its a morale breaker for me. Like mom saying clean your room, dad says whats the point, nobody else is going in your room. That type of feeling.

Comment: @Daniel Can you add examples of the task and how it was shot down? From the comments by Dwizum, it seems like the Senior finds little to no value in the work you should be doing and isn't telling you to not do it, just expressing his disinterest in it.

Comment: @Shadowzee, that's exactly what it is. Not a morale booster as a new hire. How would you handle that?

Comment: @Daniel I wouldn't worry about the senior dev and what he says too much. He doesn't sound interested or concerned about your work and probably has more important stuff to worry about. I would just hope that the CTO would give you the morale boost you need or push other members to assist you if you are having problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How should I proceed?

Under normal circumstances, you should ultimately do what your *direct boss* asks you to do. However, you indicate that your direct boss is the CTO, and he sent you over to the Sen Dev.

First I suggest you tell the Sen Dev that the CTO insisted on those other tasks. If after that, the Sen Dev insist on doing theirs I suggest you get on your way so you don't waste time, however...

I suggest you also **document the task change**, an email to the CTO and Sen Dev should do it, something like:

> Hello Sen Dev. I have started working on tasks X and Y as discussed. I am copying CTO so he can be up to date to the changes and progress, and if there is anything else you two would like to mention regarding the project.

Communication is key in situations like this, not only to be efficient and productive, but to avoid possible fallout on you.

Answer (score 0):

The tasks "not being important" do not make them unassigned.

You do the work assigned by the CTO.  You report to your direct supervisor that you are doing work assigned by the CTO, and keep them informed of your progress.

If the senior dev instructs you to *NOT* execute the assignments given to you by the CTO, then the US Navy has *EXACTLY* the action plan you need:

> 1024. **Contradictory and Conflicting Orders** If an enlisted person in the naval service receives an order, which annuls, suspends or modifies one received from another superior, he or she shall immediately represent the facts to the  superior  from  whom  the  last  order  was received.  If,  after  such  representation,  the superior from whom the last order was received should insist upon the execution of that order, it shall  be  obeyed.  The  person  receiving  and executing such order shall report the circumstances as soon  as practicable to the superior from whom the original order was received.

Comment: Wesley, an old friend of mine was a Marine so I am familiar with 1024, but not sure if thats what I need to do.

Comment: @Daniel - The military has given *CENTURIES* of thought in how to handle these situations.  You don't have to be sure. Those who came up with this were sure.  You just have to trust that they worked through *ALL* the alternatives, and this is what they resolved at.

Comment: @WesleyLong That may be the correct rule for the military, but it doesn't mean it's the correct rule in all circumstances.  The distinction between officer and enlisted is usually not replicated in technical fields.

Comment: The two settings are close enough that following these directions will keep your proverbial bacon out of the fire.